# How to change the adjustment of the chapternumber in the titleformat to foreground

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

i tried to set the layout for my current document. but i have a problem with customizing the chapternumber.

I want a similar layout like the bjornstrup style and uses the titleformat.

How can i format the \chapternumber to adjust it at the foreground? Or is there any workaround for it? Maybe I'm completely wrong with my {-20pt} and there is a much easier way to set the chapternumber in defined area?

Thanks for the help.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\titleformat
{\chapter}      
[display]
{\Huge\bfseries\itshape}
{\textcolor{gray}{\thechapter}}
{-20pt}
{\colorbox{gray!30}{\parbox[c][40pt][c]{\linewidth}{\Large\scshape\centering#1}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{I am the first Chapter}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

And my output looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the chapternumber inside the gray colorbox, like this:

```
{\colorbox{gray!30}{\rlap{\raisebox{20pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textcolor{gray}{\thechapter}}}\parbox[c][40pt][c]{\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{\Large\scshape\centering#1}}}
```

By the way, I decreased the width of the `\parbox` by `2\fboxsep` so that the `colorbox` will be as wide as the text. You need to use `\usepackage{calc}` for this to work. Alternatively you could set `\fboxsep` to `0pt`.

Comment: Thanks. Especially for the advice with the fbpxsep. but with your solution it also marks the \tableofcontents with the 0. which i didnt want. how can i provide this marking?

Comment: `\usepackage{ifthen}` and then use `\ifthenelse{\value{chapter}=0}{}{\rlap{\raisebox{20pt}[0pt][0pt]{\textcolor{gray}{\thechapter}}}}`

Comment: Yes thats it. Thanks a lot for the fast response!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `block` style, and use the chapter number in the last argument of `\titleformat`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\titleformat
{\chapter}
[block]
{\Huge\itshape\bfseries}
{}
{0pt}
{\colorbox{gray!30}{\makebox[0pt]{~\raisebox{13pt}[0pt]{\color{gray}\thechapter}}\parbox[c][40pt][c]{\linewidth}{\Large\scshape\centering#1}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{I am the first Chapter}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But that would make my grey box larger than wanted. The idea of Piet works great.

Comment: @dokutaefer: To obtain a box with the height you want, it's enough to add an optional `[0pt]` to `\raisebox` to fool LaTeX and make it believe the raised box has 0 height. Please see my updated answer.